# PHP - parse_ini_file with | value

Tags: php

parse_ini_file() cant read value something like this:

```
bot_virtualhostname = |c00FF3366VIVA
bot_commandtrigger = !
```

i cant give double quotes, bcoz ghost++ https://code.google.com/p/ghostplusplus/ will use " as value too.

can someone give alternative to read value?
im newbie in PHP

Comment: This makes no sense! Clarify: _"i cant give double quotes, bcoz ghost++ https://code.google.com/p/ghostplusplus/ will use " as value too."_

Comment: ex: when use "!" , bot will BOT-VICTORY: Command trigger: "

Comment: Do you mean you can't have a `"` in the file or not in the array returned by parse_ini_file()?

Comment: i cant give double quotes like "!", bcoz ghost++ will read " too

Answer (score 1):

Might have to use some of the `file()` options to get rid of newlines and/or trim `$key` and `$value` if spaces aren't consistant around the `=`:

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.ini', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(' = ', $line);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

If the inability to use `"` is the only peculiarity and you need the sections etc.

```
$string = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.ini');
$string = preg_replace('/(\s?=\s?)(.*)\r/', '$1"$2"', $string);
$result = parse_ini_string($string);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\tes\parse.php on line 5

Comment: That means you have a line with no `=` most likely.  You only gave 2 lines and they both had an `=`.